# You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network.

Tags: windows-server-2016, sql-server-2016

I am getting this error daily on my web server that is trying to connect SQL Server.

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network. If joining a domain, go to System in Control Panel to change the computer name and try again. If joining a workgroup, choose another workgro
"
Both Server are on Windows 2016.
SQ
I have already 
 1. checked the domain controller and found no duplicate entries
 2. using different aliases for multiple IP on same SQL server
 3. Checked all the server in the environmnet for any duplicate name and found nothing.

Can you please help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

-Check networking: Can you ping the server? Is DNS working for the server?

-Check SQL setup: Is it the default instance or do you need to specify an instance?

-Check using a different application/server: Can another server connect to the SQL server? Can you use an ODBC connection and will that work?

All of this will narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: I have already done all the Aaove steps and found no issue.